# Symfony2 entity foreign keys

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, foreign-keys, entity

I can't figure it out..

Why I haven't access to `Country` table?

`countryName` should show `Great Britain` but it doesn't.

This is my dump($User):

[image]

My my piece of code of `User` entity:

```
 /**
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Dashboard\MainBundle\Entity\Country", cascade={"persist"})
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="country_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=true)
 *
 */
private $countryId;
```

And my piece of code of `Country` Entity:

```
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on how you get the user maybe it is a lazy load that you are using which will get the country only if you call the getter explicitly, to always get a country with the user try :

```
 /**
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Dashboard\MainBundle\Entity\Country", cascade={"persist"}, fetch="EAGER")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="country_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=true)
 *
 */
private $countryId;
```

But still we need to know how you are getting the user the lazy load may override the fetch eager.

Comment: I'm getting the user by `$User = $this->getUser();`

Comment: what do you mean by do a forms with foreign keys by form builder?

Comment: I thinking how to connect this two table in one form. (Profile option -> fill in (adding) details and display it - User and country).

Comment: you should create a form type for editing user profile http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html when user open his profile it would be a form where he can see his profile and same time edit it

Comment: Yes, I got it. Everything works fine, except this countryId. I have no idea how to handle it. This is my form: http://pastebin.com/6FeN29Gm

Comment: i cannot help much i have no access to pastebin.com i live in china and that chinese firewall is a bi***

Comment: Oh, I feel sorry for you :| Is any other site where I can paste it in?

Comment: not sure what works haha, hum lets go on instant chat pass me your form part of countryId, not sure how to go on chat tho , you can pass it here

Comment: `  public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
        $builder
                ->add('firtsName', 'text', array(
                    'label' => 'first_name',
                    'required' => FALSE
                ))
                ->add('countryId', 'text', array(
                    'label' => 'country',
                    'required' => FALSE
                ));
    }` Here it is, How Can I handle adding and displaying country in User profile? :)

Comment: try this ->add('countryId', 'entity', array(
    'class' => 'YourBundle:Country',
    'property' => 'country', 'required' => false
));

Comment: I do not believe, You are my God! I have dropdown and list all the countires, just as I wanted. I don't know how you repay you, THANK YOU

Comment: 1000$ to my paypal should be fine :p kidding glad to help

Answer (score 1):

Your `Country` object is now only a Proxy object - `dump` function don't call a Doctrine to get a related object. Try before dump get your object for example:

```
dump($User->getCountry()):
dump($User);
```

OR try left join you `Country` in QueryBuilder

OR find a information about lazy load in Doctrine2 [here](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorials/extra-lazy-associations.html)